# C++ string push_back function not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to generate strings with {0, 1, 2} using an integer queue to store numbers until I am ready to check if they are binary numbers. I am starting with single digits and then appending them to get longer and longer number strings. So the order I am trying to get is 0, 1, 2, 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012 e.t.c. The problem I am having though is that when I dequeue an integer from my queue, turn it into a string and try to append it with {0, 1, 2} using s.push_back(app), nothing is appended. Below is my code and output.

```
int main()
{
  string s; //holds strings of numbers that come from the int queue                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  bool isBin; //holds the boolean value returned from recognizer                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  int count=0; //while loop counter to not go over 20 iterations                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Queue myQ; //queue created to hold all values generated                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  int numHolder; //holds values dequeued from int queue to be turned into string                                                                                                                                                                                              


  myQ.enQueue(0);//queue 3 initial values to work with                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  myQ.enQueue(1);
  myQ.enQueue(2);

  while(count<=20)//while loop doesnt go over 20 iterations of binary numbers                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    {
      numHolder=myQ.deQueue();//holds int values dequeued from queue                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      s=to_string(numHolder);//converts the int from queue to a string                                                                                                                                                                                                        

      /* isBin=recognizer(s);//send the string to the recognizer                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      if(isBin==true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          cout<<s<<endl;//prints string if it is binary number                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          count++;//increment counter because string was binary                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          }*/
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++)//this loop adds 0 then 1 then 2 to the end of each dequeued string                                                                                                                                                                               
        {
          char app = i;
          s.push_back(app);//this is where string is appended with 0 1 or 2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          cout<<s<<endl;
          int newNum=stoi(s);//new appended string is turned into integer                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          myQ.enQueue(newNum);//new integer is put into queue                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          s.pop_back();//pops back the string so other numbers can be created with the original dequeued string                                                                                                                                                               

        }
      count++;
    }
      // }// end of while                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

}// end of main
```

output:

0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

I can tell by the output it has the right order for the first characters but nothing is being appended to them because the string push_back function is not working. Please help!

Comment: `s=to_strung(numHolder);` overwrites the contents of `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char app=i` stores the characters whose binary value is `0` `1` and `2`, not the characters `'0'`, `'1'` and `'2'`.

Try `char app = '0'+i;`

In C/C++ `char` is both a number type and the traditional way to store a single character.  The conversion from `int` just treats `char` like a number type.